# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous when calculating similarity measure between 2 vectors

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of source vector and a list of target vector :

I would like to calculate for each source vector its similarity measure with every target vector .

For this I did this function :

```
def calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs, threshold=0):
        """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source document & all the target documents."""
        results = []   
        for doc1 in source_doc:            
            source_vec = vectorize(doc1)
            #print(source_vec) 
            for doc in target_docs:            
                target_vec = vectorize(doc)
                #print(target_vec)
                sim_score = np.dot(source_vec, target_vec) / (np.linalg.norm(source_vec) * np.linalg.norm(target_vec))
                print(sim_score)
                if sim_score > threshold:
                    results.append({
                        'score' : sim_score,
                        'source sentence' : doc1, 
                        'target sentence' : doc

                    })
            # Sort results by score in desc order
            results.sort(key=lambda k : k['score'] , reverse=True)


        return results
```

But I get an error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-c025176ea126> in <module>()
----> 1 sim_scores = calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs)

<ipython-input-185-5c04abb8d5ed> in calculate_similarity2(source_doc, target_docs, threshold)
     10                 sim_score = np.dot(source_vec, target_vec) / (np.linalg.norm(source_vec) * np.linalg.norm(target_vec))
     11                 print(sim_score)
---> 12                 if sim_score > threshold:
     13                     results.append({
     14                         'score' : sim_score,

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can you help me to resolve this error please?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently `sim_score` is a numpy array there, and `sim_score > threshold` will result in an array of booleans. That can't be used in an if statement.